# Why is this question not welcome?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

The following question was recently closed:

[Turn off keyboard shortcut](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295196/turn-off-keyboard-shortcut)

The specific reason for closing is not accurate and I assume reflects the lack of options. But what then was the reason for closing? There clearly seems to be some conflict in this community whether the question should be closed or not since there were a number of comments left stating that the question should be left open, e.g.

> This is a functionality of Mathematica that's that's poorly documented, making this a useful question for other people:

I assume that a number of the up votes on the question are reactions to this as well (or they are votes in favor of the question itself). The (accepted) answer also seems to indicate that the question was not obvious.

In contrast, there was not a single argument given for why the question is not appropriate. Well, there was one hilarious abusive comment which was later deleted (either by themselves in shame or by a moderator I don't know). But the fact that the question was closed even after it had been answered indicates that some people must feel really strongly that it should be closed, although not strongly enough to explain why.

The question is not abound *programming* in mathematica, but it certainly is a question quite specific to mathematica with an answer that seems to require some expertise in mathematica (and even the answer required some code inside mathematica to fix, at least for me).  But it seems like it is worth clarifying what the problem was with this question, if only for being able to explain to askers of future questions of this form why their question is not wanted.

Comment: Even though the particular question has been re-opened, the complete lack of any response or explanation here is troubling.

Comment: I can't speak for the people that voted to close, but I suspect that it might be because on a first/quick read, it sounds like you're asking to change the keyboard behavior in the OS to get around typos, and not a Mathematica issue. Stylesheet internals are not a familiar topic to many expert users, and many might have failed to make that connection immediately. I think the "close vote queue" also fuels some of the pile-on votes from users who don't read all of the context in the comments, but that's a Stack Exchange feature, not something we can control.

Comment: I get this was not a pleasant experience as a new user, but on the bright side, there was strong support in the comments (as evidenced by the upvotes on the question and answers) and reopened by the community. Your question is 100% on topic for this site. As to how it could have been improved, I think a screenshot showing the messed up cell contents would've made it obvious that it is about the stylesheet/rich text formatting in the Mathematica notebook .

Comment: @rm-rf: I should say that the outcome (for me) was definitely positive, and the fact that the answer came before the question was closed meant that it really wasn't unpleasant either. I was just trying to work out here if I was missing something. You give another plausible suggestion that makes sense to me.